# Android : How to get broadcast intent from pending intent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I am using a pending intent to fire alarms.

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Notes.mContext, (int)note.m_id, intentToBeBroadcast, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
```

How do I get the intentToBeBroadcast back from the pending intent?

Comment: what do you passing in intentToBeBroadcast?

Comment: Well, you can't get it back from the PendingIntent. But you can update the existing intent if you want to.

Comment: Thanks. I too realized that it is not possible

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept the answer, so this question doesn't stay on the "unanswered" list.